# How Can I replace Files With Regex?

Tags: asp.net, regex, visual-studio, webforms

I have an aspnet webform application and I have more than 1000 server.transfer like below

```
Server.Transfer("~/General/Personnel/List.aspx");
```

I want to add /V2 after "~" in all files.
Expected is

```
Server.Transfer("~/V2/General/Personnel/List.aspx");
```

This is only sample so I have different folder structure like General/Users/Personnel, Customer/Personnel, Users/List/Personnel only /Personnel is common for every server transfer I want to add /V2 after "~" in all files which contains "/Personnel". How Can I do this with regex or another else in visual studio.

Comment: You could search for "~ in vs code and replace it with   "~/V2/

Comment: @gajendragarg I cant because there are many files which are does not contain /Personnel like "~/General/Customer". I dont want to change this files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add “/V2” before all files containing /Personnel, you can try this regex to replace them.

You can click Ctrl+Shift+F to open this window and replace  `~/(.*)/Personnel` into `~/V2/$1/Personnel`
[image]